# need some guidance for a delta extracting script for maya

Tags: python, maya

i have no prior experience with python scripting in maya so i really need some help with this script .

cmds.invertShape("object0"," object1")

this is a script that i found which extracts deltas from corrective shapes in maya and each time i have to manually enter the name of both the original mesh and the corrective mesh to extract the deltas , it would be nicer if the script would automatically detect the name of the selected objects so that the script can directly be executed from the shelf rather than opening the editor again and again.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: with this script  above i can extract deltas from corrective shapes but i have to manually enter the name of those objects eg object0 and object1 each time and for that i have to keep opening the script editor , it would be better if i could directly select the 2 mesh and execute this command without the need of having to enter their names manually ..can you guide me or show me how it can be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to select object0 first then object1 and execute this:

```
selection = cmds.ls(sl=True)
cmds.invertShape(selection[0],selection[1])
```